# two different attention methods for seq2seq

Tags: sequence-to-sequence, attention-mechanism

I see two different ways of applying attention in seq2seq:

(a) the context vector (the weighted sum of encoder hidden states) fed into the output softmax, as shown in the diagram below. The diagram is from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention).

[image: from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention.]

(b) the context vector fed into the decoder input as shown the diagram below. The diagram is from [here](https://guillaumegenthial.github.io/sequence-to-sequence.html).

[image]

What are the pros and the cons of the two different approaches? Is there any paper comparing the two?

Answer (score 1):

(a) is Luong's attention mechanism ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04025v5)) while (b) is  Bahdanau's mechanism ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473))